# How can we access a labelled statement from another method

Tags: java, label

I need to access a loop in method 1 from method 2, on onclick function of method 2

```
method1()
{
label:
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
System.out.println("something");
}
}


method2()
{
continue label;
}
```

Comment: You can't. `continue` must be inside the block of the `for` loop. See [JLS  §14.16. The continue Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16): *A `continue` statement must refer to a label within the immediately enclosing method, constructor, initializer, or lambda body. **There are no non-local jumps**.*.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it seems like you could just call `method1()`, since the label is at the beginning of the method.

If the label isn't at the beginning of the method, you could make a new method such that the label IS at the beginning of the method.  So instead of:

```
method1()
{
    thing11();
    label:
    thing22():
    thing33():
}

method2()
{
    continue label;
}
```

you could do:

```
method1()
{
    thing11();
    label:
    method3():
}

method2()
{
    method3();
}

method3()
{
    thing22():
    thing33():
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void forLoop() {  
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println("something");
    }
}    

method1() {
    forLoop();
}

method2() {
    forLoop();
}
```

Take the for loop out and put it in another method so that both methods can access it. This is an alternative way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It is not possible.

The only fully non-local control-flow construct in Java are exceptions. You could rig something up with exceptions and trampolines, probably.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is refactor the loop into a third method, and call it from both `method1` and `method2`.  In Java, you can't "jump" from one method to another like what you're describing.

Comment: Well, you can, using exceptions. There's a nice paper showing that exceptions can be more powerful than continuations. Continuations, in turn, are well-known to be universal, i.e. equivalent to `GOTO`; ergo, exceptions are at least as powerful as `GOTO`. Now, whether you *want* to do that is a whole other question … Plus, you'd have to re-structure the code of course, something like this is not just syntactic sugar, it requires a global restructuring of the code.

Comment: And _that_ would be doing it entirely _unlike_ what OP described.